# StreamReader read last line that contains

Tags: c#, streamreader

I am trying to read from a text file that has multiple outputs from when writing to it but when I want to read from the textfile that I already outputted stuff to, I want to choose the last entry(bear in mind each entry when writing has 5 lines and I just want the line containing "Ciphered text:")

But with this it is reading the lines containing that but I cannot work how to make it show only the last entry containing the string I specified.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ReadLastContain
{
    class StreamRead
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string TempFile = @"C:\Users\Josh\Desktop\text2.txt";
            using (var source = new StreamReader(TempFile))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = source.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (line.Contains("Ciphered Text:"))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How about Read from End ?

Comment: can  you add the contents of the file in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to use LINQ for better readability:

```
string lastCipheredText = File.ReadLines(TempFile)
    .LastOrDefault(l => l.Contains("Ciphered Text:"));
```

it is `null` if there was no such line. If you can't use LINQ:

```
string lastCipheredText = null;
while ((line = source.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (line.Contains("Ciphered Text:"))
    {
        lastCipheredText = line;
    }
}
```

It will be overwritten always, so you automatically get the last line that contained it.

Comment: thankyou tim that's great it works! and thanks for the quick reply :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use *Linq*:

```
var text = File
  .ReadLines(@"C:\Users\Josh\Desktop\text2.txt")
  .LastOrDefault(line => line.Contains("Ciphered Text:"));

if (null != text) // if there´s a text to print out
  Console.WriteLine(text);
```

Comment: thankyou Dmitry I used tim's though but still thanks!